# What is web app runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I was going through the node-webkit package for creating desktop application. and it is mentioned that node-webkit is web app runtime. Please explain what is "web app runtime"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a system that interprets your code and runs it on another platform, in this case on various desktop operating systems.

Your code needs to interact with the runtime only, and doesn't need to care about platform specific details.